# How to sort json array in php by key?

Tags: php

I'm trying to sort json array by key in php. Although I use **usort**, it's not working.
My json array is

```
$data = [
    {
        "profile_name": "J3S",
        "post_count": 9
    },
    {
        "profile_name": "John",
        "post_count": 3
    },
    {
        "profile_name": "sato",
        "post_count": 10
    }
]
```

I would like to sort the array by post_count.
Here is my code that I tried.

```
$data = json_encode($data, true);

usort($data, function ($a, $b) {
    return $a['post_count'] <=> $b['post_count'];
});
```

Could you please help me?

Comment: Is `$data` a JSON string? Because that's not a valid PHP structure.

Comment: No such thing as a JSON array as JSON is the string representation of array data (and objects).  So your sorting on a string.  In other words, sort the Array first, then turn it into JSON.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`array_multisort`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php) to do this efficiently:

```
$array = json_decode($data, true);
array_multisort(array_column($array, 'post_count'), SORT_ASC, $array);
echo json_encode($array, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Output:

```
[
  { "profile_name": "John", "post_count": 3 } 
  { "profile_name": "J3S", "post_count": 9 },
  { "profile_name": "sato", "post_count": 10 },
]
```

If you want to sort by `post_count` descending, just change the `SORT_ASC` to `SORT_DESC` in the call to `array_multisort`.

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/ePMSC)

Note this code assumes `$data` is actually a JSON string. If it is actually the array represented by the JSON in the question, you can skip the `json_decode` step.

Answer (score 0):

You have to decode the json, not encode it:

```
$data = '[
    {
        "profile_name": "J3S",
        "post_count": 9
    },
    {
        "profile_name": "John",
        "post_count": 3
    },
    {
        "profile_name": "sato",
        "post_count": 10
    }
]';

$data = json_decode($data, true);

usort($data, function ($a, $b) {
    return $a['post_count'] <=> $b['post_count'];
});
```

I asume your json is a string because if it's not that's not valid php.

Output ( var_dump( $data ); ):

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["profile_name"]=>
    string(4) "John"
    ["post_count"]=>
    int(3)
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["profile_name"]=>
    string(3) "J3S"
    ["post_count"]=>
    int(9)
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    ["profile_name"]=>
    string(4) "sato"
    ["post_count"]=>
    int(10)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by `usort()` function.

Add a callback function and compare the `profile_count` each time.

```
<?php
$data = [
    ["profile_name"=> "J3S", "post_count"=> 9],
    ["profile_name"=> "John", "post_count"=> 3],
    ["profile_name"=> "sato", "post_count"=> 10]
];
function cmpBySort($a, $b) {
    return $a['post_count'] - $b['post_count'];
}
usort($data, 'cmpBySort');
echo '<pre>';print_r($data);echo '</pre>';
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [profile_name] => John
            [post_count] => 3
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [profile_name] => J3S
            [post_count] => 9
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [profile_name] => sato
            [post_count] => 10
        )

)
```